# Attempting to open the latest file with a wildcard then using include

Tags: ruby, sorting, select

I'm using the following to open a file within a directory that contains 'abc' in the filename. The wildcard is used as the rest of the filename includes a timestamp (time and date the file was created).

```
      required = ["this", "two"]
      log = Dir['*.log'].select { |f| f.include?('abc')}
      result = required.all? do |phrase|
          log.any? { |line| line.include?(phrase) }
      end
      index = result ? "Pass" : "Fail"
```

The above script is part of an automation process, so the full name will not be known (file created in one of the initial steps)

Is there a way to sort files by mtime prior to the .select?

I've tried .sort and .max_by prior to .select and get private method error

```
       log = Dir['*.log'].max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}.select { |f| f.include?('abc')}
```

I've tried it after .select, which gets the latest file but throws and underfined method 'any?' - this seems incorrect anyway as i should be sorting before selecting.

any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`#max_by` is going to return at most one element. You should be able to use `#sort_by` to arrange the files according to their `mtime`s, `#reverse` this list, and then use `#find` (or its alias `#detect`) to pluck out the first element matching the predicate (`{ |f| f[/abc/] }`, in this case).